# C# BindingList<T> as Datasource for DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have been using BindingLists to show object data for Threads running in my application.
This has always worked great.

Now I want to show my own object's properties in a `DataGridView`, the binding of the empty `BindingList` succeeds without trouble.
However when adding elements to the list, I get an exception stating there must be columns in the `DataGridView`

The code which works:

```
BindingList<Thread> threads = new BindingList<Thread>();
dgThreadStates.DataSource = new BindingSource() { DataSource = threads }; //DataGridView
Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(handler.handleEntries));
threads.Add(t);
```

This however does not seem to work:

```
public class Customer
{
    public System.Guid GUID;

    public string FirstName;
    public string MiddleName;
    public string LastName;

    public string Postcode;
    public string HouseNo;
    public string StreetName;
    public string City;
}
```

The Method:

```
BindingList<Customer> savedCustomers = new BindingList<Customer>();
dgvCustomers.DataSource = new BindingSource() { DataSource = savedCustomers };  //DataGridView
savedCustomers.Add(new Customer());
```

I'll get this exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll. Additional Information: No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.
```

Comment: you use fields in your customer class but binding works with properties not fields.

Comment: @Ralf You are right! Please post this as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databinding works with properties not fields. The DataGridView won't find Properties for generating columns (i assume you use autocreatecolumns in your grid) in your class and refuses to work without any columns.

So you need to replace your fields with (atleast automatic) properties.

```
public class Customer
{
    public System.Guid GUID { get; set; }
    // etc. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible solution

```
var list = new List<users>()
{
    new Person { Name = "Robin", },
    new Person { Name = "Cleef", },
};
var bindingList = new BindingList<users>(list);
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
grid.DataSource = source;
```